# Accessing win8 hdd over usb breaks permissions. "Failed to enumerate objects in the container.Access is denied."

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, permissions

I connected my Win8(OS1) hdd over usb to another win8(OS2) and accessed my user profile from OS1 on OS2.

When OS1 was booted up again all of my premissions are now broken and no applications work.

When I try to modify the permissions and give me access to my own profile again it shows the message "Failed to enumerate objects in the container.Access is denied."

Comment: How do you connect two PCs over usb? Used USB networking cable?

Comment: The physical hdd was removed from OS1 and connected to OS2 over usb. A temporary fix was to goto security -> advanced -> auditing and changing the owner to everyone on the OS1 hdd. This could have security implications but I was able to successfully boot OS1 and run my applications to do a backup and reformat.